# How to create desktop application using fully customized UI?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qstyle, qtwidgets

Have a look at this figure below, which is a Quick Book Enterprise Solution 2014

[image: QuickBook Enterprise Edition 2014]

Judging by its interface (not its DLL), I don't think you can easily guess with what platform/language does the above application was created. Qt? .NET? Java? It has its own border, custom menu, ... etc. In a simple wording, "it has totally customized UI that make it stand from the rest".

What do we need to be able to create this kind of application with fully customized UI? And what if I add cross platform aspect in this application? Different customized widgets in different OSes... but maintaining the same level of UI appearance...

I have previous experience with Qt, .. but I am not sure Qt can do this.. or is it?

Comment: Perhaps, you want a custom QStyle, or just thrive drop the QStyle concept and use the qt 5 theming?

Comment: Aah, thanks for pointing me to Qt 5 theming. I haven't explore it until that topic. It seems like a reasonable approach for me, e.g : http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, you can write your own plugin similar to the [existing qt style plugins](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtstyleplugins/source/7bd6205398b2d89b3ac083b2f6f00b197f40057a).

Here, you can find an example how to write widget based style plugins with Qt 5:

[QtWidgets 5.0: Style Plugin Example](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtstyleplugins/source/7bd6205398b2d89b3ac083b2f6f00b197f40057a)

You would work with the [QStylePlugin](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QStylePlugin.html) plugin interface.

If you are looking into a bit more modern solution, you may find [this qml style and theme support](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-usecase-styling.html) documentation useful.